# Copy/Paste from InputWS to TargetWS based on column headers

Tags: vba, excel

I was able to piece together the following module.  The code works perfectly to copy the correct column data but is defining row 218 as the "last row" rather than the real last row, which is 3929.  Coincidently, row 218 and 219 have data populated in every cell, with no leading or trailing spaces.  If I define the last row by row number

```
(TargetWS.Cells(3929, Cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues)
```

the module works correctly.  Since this code will be the backbone of a workflow to copy/paste individual employee data into a master table for the particular common headers chosen, defining it in this manner is not tenable.

I attempted to start the database sheet from scratch to ensure there were no underlying formatting issues attributing to this problem but no joy.  I know I'm missing something small.

```
Sub CopyByHeader()

    Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
    Set CurrentWS = ActiveSheet

    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Set SourceWS = ActiveSheet
    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Integer: SourceHeaderRow = 1
    Dim SourceCell As Range

    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    Set TargetWS = Workbooks("4.4.5.3 Database.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Set TargetHeader = TargetWS.Range("A2:K2")

    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim SourceCol As Integer

    SourceWS.Activate
    For Each cell In TargetHeader
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set SourceCell = Rows(SourceHeaderRow).Find _
                (cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                SourceCol = SourceCell.Column
                RealLastRow = Columns(SourceCol).Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                Searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                If RealLastRow > SourceHeaderRow Then
                    Range(Cells(SourceHeaderRow + 1, SourceCol), Cells(RealLastRow, _
                        SourceCol)).Copy
                TargetWS.Cells(RealLastRow + 1, cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    CurrentWS.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. My hunch is that `Set TargetWS = Worksheets(1)` is not giving you the worksheet you think it is... change `Worksheets(1)` to your actual worksheet name (i.e. `Worksheets("MyWorksheet")`) and I'm betting your issue disappears :). Try to avoid assigning variables with `ActiveSheet` and sheet index numbers.

Comment: It could also be that `sourceCell` is not the proper cell as well, so you're getting the last cell in another column instead

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Without seeing your data I can't reproduce your issue either.  Perhaps you could clarify your problem; I think i and others are guessing to fill in the blanks.  Is the problem that `RealLastRow` is not calculated properly? If you're not sure see [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) to step through the code and figure out the variable values.

Comment: Try changing `RealLastRow = Columns(SourceCol).Find(...).Row` to `RealLastRow = TargetWS.Columns(SourceCol).Find(...).Row`

Comment: If I replace "TargetWS.Cells(RealLastRow + 1, cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" with TargetWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues it selects the correct "first empty row" but pastes results straight down column A instead of across row 3928. I will work on a sample sheet I can provide for review, as I can't include the original data. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Instead of relying on the `SourceWS.Activate`, be sure to specify the worksheet for every range that you're working with

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your Find() method for determining your last row. Based on a quick look the documentation my guess is that it's getting thrown off by the row being completely full.

If you have any columns that have data in every row you can replace

```
RealLastRow = Columns(SourceCol).Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
            Searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

with

```
RealLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
```

where "colNum" is the number of the column that has no empty cells (e.g. column A would be 1).

Comment: Even if the column is full, `.Find( ... xlPrevious).row` should return the proper row number regardless

Answer (score 0):

if the original sheet (Worksheet1) column is removed, the worksheet (Worksheet2) which has copied values will not be removed as well, resulting in stuck copied values.